# Counterexample for size of field automorphism group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm looking for a counterexample of the following (false) statement:

If $ K \subset M \subset L $ with $ [ L : K ] < \infty $ and $ |\text{Aut} (L / K)| = 1 $, then $ |\text{Aut} (M / K)| = 1 $.

Basically looking a finite algebraic field extension $ M / K $ with nontrivial $ K $-automorphisms which cannot be extended to $K$-automorphisms of $L$.

Comment: I started writing down an argument why $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $M=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of{2+i})$ is also such an example. Then I realized that this is more or less identical to Pisco's excellent example. They use $p=(1+i\sqrt{7})/2$ and $p^{1/3}$ in place of $q=2+i$ and its cubic root. Both $p$ and $q$ are primes in their respective quadratic extensions linearly disjoint from the third cyclotomic field, and that makes things click. Anyway, this point of view makes it relatively easy to believe that the $q^{1/3}$ (or $p^{1/3}$) is the only zero of its minimal polynomial in the field it generates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Galois closure of $L$ has to be a bit complicated in order for counterexample to occur. Let $G$ be the subgroup of $S_6$ generated by $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 &5 &4 &3 &6 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \begin{pmatrix}1 &5 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}2 &6 \end{pmatrix}$$
it has order $36$. Stabilizer of $1$ is given by
$$H = \{1, (35)(46), (246), (24)(35), (264), (26)(35)\}$$
Note that $G$ contains odd permutation, so $G\cap A_6 \lhd G$.

Now let $f \in K[x]$ be a degree $6$ separable polynomial such that its Galois group is $G$, $E$ be the splitting field of $f$. Let $L = E^H$, since $H$ is the stablizer of a point, we can assume $L = K(\alpha)$, where is $\alpha$ a root of $f$. Denote $M = E^{G\cap A_6}$, then $M\subset L$ and $[M:K]=|\text{Aut}(M/K)| = 2$. Next we claim $|\text{Aut}(L/K)|=1$, it suffices to show $L$ contains no other roots of $f$ except $\alpha$, this is true by looking at the elements of $H$: each indices $2,3,4,5,6$ are moved by $H$.

---

**A concrete example**: let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^6-x^3+2 = 0$, $$L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \qquad M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}) \qquad K=\mathbb{Q}$$ The Galois group of this polynomial is easily seen to be $G$ above. Of course, a direct proof of $|\text{Aut}(L/K)| = 1$ is also not difficult by writing down roots explicitly.

Comment: Excellent solution - if you don't mind, could please you give a little more detail on why that polynomial has Galois group $G$?